# wrinting persian in kivy list view item

Tags: android, python, listview, kivy, persian

I've another problem in kivy programming.
I wanht to write persian in my App and in used Arabi_reshaper for it.
when i try to do sth like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
import arabic_reshaper
Builder.load_string(
'''
<TI>
    but: but
    Button:
        id: but
        font_name: 'data/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf'
        font_size: '45dp'   
''')

class TI(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TI, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.but.text = get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(u'سلام دنیا'))


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return TI()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

it works properly.
but when i try to write persian in listview item it only show dark squares...
my sample code for list item is this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
import arabic_reshaper
Builder.load_string(
'''
<TI>
    but: but
    ListView:
        id: but 
''')

class TI(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TI, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.but.item_strings = [get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(n))  for n in name]


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return TI()


if __name__ == '__main__':
MyApp().run()
```

where is the problem?
Is there any way to correct it?
how can i use persian in list view in kivy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the font, just like you did in working example, where you are using `DejaVuSans`, since the default font, `DroidSans`, apparently doesn't support your language. You can do this through list adapter:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label

Builder.load_string(
'''
#:import la kivy.adapters.listadapter 
#:import lbl kivy.uix.label

<TI>
    but: but
    ListView:
        id: but 
        adapter: la.ListAdapter(data=[], cls=lbl.Label)

<MyLabel>:
    font_name: 'data/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf'
''')

class MyLabel(Label):
    pass

class TI(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TI, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.but.adapter.data = [u'سلام دنیا']
        self.but.adapter.cls = MyLabel

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TI()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```