# How to show text in buttons, textinputs in Persian language?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, farsi

I want to know if I can type in `Persian(Farsi)` in `python kivy`(texts in textinput, buttons, …)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wrinting persian in kivy list view item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27616652/wrinting-persian-in-kivy-list-view-item)

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex I want to type Persian in my `.kv file`.